# How can I return data (string array) from the SAXParser handler?

Tags: java, saxparser

With the below code I want to return a array of data back from the SAX parser for each data inside the nodes. I have a array list which will keep the data under each leaf node. How do I use this data outside the handler or return it? -

```
public class ReadXMLFile {

   public static xmldataparser(String argv[]) {

    try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    boolean burl = false;
    boolean bip = false;
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("URL")) {
            burl = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IP")) {
            bip = true;
        }



    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (burl) {
            System.out.println("URL : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            a.add(new String(ch, start, length));
            burl = false;
        }

        if (bip) {
            System.out.println("IP : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bip = false;
            a.add(new String(ch, start, length));
        }


    }

     };
  }
return <the array from the handler(this is where I need help)>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the variables that store your result (e.g. `a` in this case) public or create a getter method for them, you will be able to access them and use any information stored there in code outside of the handler class.

Answer (score 0):

Create another class and extends `DefaultHandler`. Create method in handler class(ex:-sample). Before calling `SAXParser.parse(filename,handler)` make a call sample method. Create list as a global variable. You can add the required values to the list. Finally return the list from the sample method.

Comment: Please add some code and formatting to your answer - it is difficult to read. You can use a numbered list in your answer for better quality. Thank you for your contribution